# Angular UI Router Nested State resolve in child states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In an angular app I'm working on, I'd like there to be an abstract parent state which must resolve certain dependencies for all of its children's states. Specifically, I'd like all states requiring an authenticated user to inherit that dependency from some authroot state.

I'm running into issues having the parent dependency not always being re-resolved. Ideally, I'd like to have the parent state check that the user is still logged in for any child state automatically. In the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies), it says

> Child states will inherit resolved dependencies from parent state(s), which they can overwrite.

I'm finding that the parent dependency is only being re-resolved if I enter any child state from a state outside the parent, but not if moving between sibling states.

In this example, if you move between states authroot.testA and authroot.testB, the GetUser method is only called once. When you move to the `other` state and back, it will get run again.

I am able to put the User dependency on each of the child states to ensure the method is called every time you enter any of those states, but that seems to defeat the purpose of the inherited dependency.

Am I understanding the docs incorrectly? Is there a way to force the parent state to re-resolve its dependencies even when the state changes between siblings?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCVLS/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.0/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(ng) {
    var app = ng.module("Test", ["ui.router"]);
    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function(sp, urp) {
        urp.otherwise("/testA");
        sp.state("authroot", {
            abstract: true, 
            url: "",
            template: "<div ui-view></div>", 
            resolve: {User: ["UserService", function(UserService) {
                        console.log("Resolving dependency...");
                        return UserService.GetUser();
                    }]}
        });
        sp.state("authroot.testA", {
            url: "/testA", 
            template: "<h1>Test A {{User|json}}</h1>", 
            controller: "TestCtrl"
        });
        sp.state("authroot.testB", {
            url: "/testB", 
            template: "<h1>Test B {{User|json}}</h1>", 
            controller: "TestCtrl"
        });
        sp.state("other", {
            url: "/other", 
            template: "<h1>Other</h1>", 
        });
    }]);
    app.controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", "User", function($scope, User) {$scope.User = User;}]);
    app.factory("UserService", ["$q", "$timeout", function($q, $timeout) {
        function GetUser() {
            console.log("Getting User information from server...");
            var d = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("Got User info.");
                d.resolve({UserName:"JohnDoe1", OtherData: "asdf"});
            }, 500);
            return d.promise;
        };
        return {
            GetUser: GetUser
        };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Test">
    <a ui-sref="authroot.testA">Goto A</a>
    <a ui-sref="authroot.testB">Goto B</a>
    <a ui-sref="other">Goto Other</a>
    <div ui-view>Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way I find the *ui-router* exceptional, is in the behaviour you've just described.

Let's think about some entity, e.g. Contact. So it would be nice to have a right side showing us the list of Contacts, the left part the detail. Please check the [The basics of using ui-router with AngularJS](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/) for quick overvie about the layout. A cite:

> ui-router fully embraces the state-machine nature of a routing system.
> It allows you to define states, and transition your application to
> those states. The real win is that it allows you to decouple nested
> states, and do some very complicated layouts in an elegant way.
>
> You need to think about your routing a bit differently, but once you
> get your head around the state-based approach, I think you will like
> it.

Ok, why that all?

Because we can have a state `Contact` representing a List. Say a fixed **list** from perspective of the **detail**. *(Skip list paging filtering now)* We can click on the list and get moved to a state `Contact.Detail(ID)`, to see just selected item. And then select another contact/item.

#### Here the advantage of nested states comes:

> The **List** (the state `Contact`) is **not** reloaded. While the child state `Contact.Detail` is.

That should explain why the "weird" behaviour should be treated as correct.

To answer your question, how to handle user state. I would use some very top sibling of a route state, with its separated view and controller and some lifecycle arround... triggered in some cycles

Answer (score 8):

Real Short answer is use:

`$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart")`

to listen for any scope changes and do appropriate actions.

Longer answer is, check out the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jasallen/SZGjN/1/

Note that I've used app.run which means i'm resolving the user for *every* state change.  If you want to limit it to state changes while authRoot is in the parentage, put the check for `$stateChangeStart` in the authRoot controller.

Comment: I ended up doing something of a mix between what you and Radim suggested - having the states resolve their own dependencies, and the states that fall outside of the hierarchy registering listeners on the  user service object

Comment: @David any way we can see what you ended up doing?  I'm running into something similar

Comment: @SonicTheLichen Sure, I'll put a fiddle together today to show you

Comment: This isn't a full example, but it shows the gist of it: http://jsfiddle.net/M2vQ5/ - every state that needs the user to be logged in needs to be a sub-state of Root.Auth, and also needs to resolve the user dependency. To reduce this repetition, I made this change...

Comment: New example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ebZj/1/ now, I can just use ResolveProvider.User to require each state to check the user is logged in. I also have a few other commonly used resolutions in my ResolveProvider

Comment: Finally, on the server side (using mvc3), the UserService calls "/User" which either returns a small user object with username, name, and a few other items, or returns a HttpUnauthorizedResult, which causes the UserService.GetUser() promise to reject

Comment: @SonicTheLichen realized I didn't @ you so here's this comment just in case

Comment: Thanks for putting those examples together for me @David.  This has been very helpful for me.