# UI Router load detail page from a list page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

AngularJS app using ui-router.
My list page loads correctly, but when clicking on links on the list page my url changes but my html on the page does not change, it remains on the list page.  What is wrong with this routing?

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config([
    '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('products', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/manageProducts/products.list.html',
                controller: 'productListCtrl'
            })
            .state('products.detail', {
                url: '/:id',
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/manageProducts/products.detail.html',
                controller: 'productDetailCtrl'
            });
    }
]);
```

Index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

On the products.list.html template:

```
<a ui-sref="products.detail({ id: 1 })">Detail for Item 1</a>
```

Should I even be using UI Router?  The list and details page are 2 distinct screens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkfRUOMlgS5qW9f4ET6p?p=preview), which should help to give an answer:

> Should I even be using UI Router? The list and details page are 2 distinct screens.

In case, that we would continue with `productDetails` state, we do loose something *(if not even a lot)*.

In the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkfRUOMlgS5qW9f4ET6p?p=preview) we can see this state definition:

```
$stateProvider

    // parent state for products.detail
    // the important thing here is that it must contain
    // ui-view="details", because the child is targeting it
    .state('products', {
      url: '/products',
      templateUrl: 'products.list.html',
      controller: 'productListCtrl'
    })
    // here, we will hook into the parent ui-view
    // that means one essential thing:
    // our scope, will be inherited from parent
    .state('products.detail', {
      url: '^/:id',
      views: {
        'detail': {
          templateUrl: 'products.detail.html',
          controller: 'productDetailCtrl'
        }
      },
    })
```

Until now we've seen the standard nested states parent/child. Next we will define the sub-state, while targeting the root `ui-view=""`

```
    // this one is as the productDetails
    // it skips parent and targets the root view
    // despite of the fact, that it is defined as sub-state of the products !
    // we won't get anything from parent state
    .state('products.detailAsRoot', {
      url: '^/product/:id',
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: 'products.detail.html',
          controller: 'productAsRootCtrl'
        }
      },
    });
```

Firstly, the inheritance in javascript/scopes is tremendously explained here:

- [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/)

And also, important is, that scopes in ui-router are inherited in a way of "view nesting"

- [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only)

A fundamental cite:

> Keep in mind that scope properties **only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested**. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).

So what is all this answer about? To say: if we will use `ui-router`, the biggest benefit is the scope inheritance. Parent can do something once... child(ren) can just reuse it.

Also see:

- [How do I prevent reload on named view, when state changes? AngularJS UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568908/)
- [Angular UI Router Nested State resolve in child states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558850/1679310)
- The [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkfRUOMlgS5qW9f4ET6p?p=preview) with working example described here

Comment: doesn't this imply that the list and detail view are both rendered? Hence, in the OP's scenario, no inheritance will occur (two distinct screens).

Answer (score 6):

I had to make the details page it's own state, as follows:

```
        .state('productDetails', {
            url: '/:id',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/manageProducts/products.detail.html',
            controller: 'productDetailCtrl'
        })
```

instead of 'product.details' I used 'productDetails'

Answer (score 4):

Using a root abstract state:

```
.state('products', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/products',
  template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('products.list', {
  url: '',
  template: '<div>Products list</div>'
})
.state('products.detail', {
  url: '/:productId',
  template: '<div>Product detail</div>'
})
```