# Angularjs Master Detail with $stateProvider does not work

Tags: angularjs, master-detail

I have tried what was helped in:
[UI Router load detail page from a list page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963247/ui-router-load-detail-page-from-a-list-page)

and I encountered a problem as the code I implemented was different overall.

Here I have the config.js:

```
.state('app.projects', {
        url: "/projects",
        templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Projects' },
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl'
    })
.state('app.project_detail', {
        url: "/project_detail",
        view: {
            'project_detail':{
            templateUrl: 'views/project_detail.html',
            controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
            }
        },
        data: { pageTitle: 'Project detail' }
    })
```

and I have the project (MASTER) html:

```
<td class="project-actions">
    <a ui-sref="app.project_detail/({project_id:1})" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a>
</td>
```

and the project_detail (DETAIL)

```
<h2> {{project_data.project_id}}</h2>
```

and finally the controller.js:

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, $state, $stateParams) {

$http.get('../crud/projects_read.php').then(function(response){
    $scope.projects = response.data;
});

};

function ProjectDetailCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, $state, $stateParams) {

    $scope.project_data = $scope.projects[$stateParams.project_id]

};
```

I think I have all set in proper manner, but
the UI-SREF does not work and I think the data does not seem to be passed from the Project --> Project Detail in the controller.js file.

Could anyone help me? I am stuck and have been trying almost whole day with different examples (can't even count!).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakes at two places

1. Change your `ui-sref` as mentioned by @Gaurav

   ```
   <a ui-sref="app.project_detail({project_id: 1})">
   ```
2. You are not telling your state that there will be a parameter :project_id

   ```
    .state('app.project_detail', {
           url: "/project_detail/:project_id",
           view: {
               'project_detail':{
               templateUrl: 'views/project_detail.html',
               controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
               }
           },
           data: { pageTitle: 'Project detail' }
       })'
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! Now I understand how to use it. :) But, the "project_detail.html" is NOT being brought to the view. Only empty contents are shown. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you access it like <div ui-view='project_detail'/> from your index file? Check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views for more info on how to use views

Comment: Thank  you, Vivz. I have actually acknowledged the concept you mentioned above. However, due to the other stuff, the UI-VIEW is not possible.

Comment: In the meantime, I realized that the $scope.project_data = $scope.projects[$stateParams.project_id] is giving me a headache. It is the data coming from the SQL. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I found out this through the console: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined at new ProjectDetailCtrl. I will take a look at it close to figure out what is wrong with it. Still, your support is really appreciated. :)

Comment: Try to create a plunker with  the same problem.

Comment: Vivz, I solved the problem. $scope.project_data = $scope.projects[$stateParams.project_id] received no data so I removed ProjectDetailCtrl function and collapsed with ProjectCtrl where it has the $scope.projects data received. Thank you for your advice!!!

Comment: Glad that u figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your ui-sref like this:

```
<a ui-sref="app.project_detail({project_id: 1})">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will keep that in mind. :)