# Angular ui-router: 1 url trigger both parent and child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I go to the url `/blog/post/edit`, 2 xhr requests trigger, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

This is how I have defined the routes:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('blog', {
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: '/blog'
    })
    .state('blog.post', {
        url: '/post',
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('blog.post.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        templateUrl: '/blog/post/edit'
    });
```

Can anyone help me figuring out why this is happening?

Comment: ;) This is a feature ;) it is not a bug. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20558850/1679310. It could be maybe weird when firstly used, but at the end, this *(I'd say)* **the biggest advantage of this tool!**

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I should really only do this when both parent and children are visible at the same time. I was just using it to organize my routes ;) You need to add an answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As quickly discussed in comments*, the nature of the `ui-router` is **to work** this way. To show nested states with their parent states

The best way how to think about it is like a ***collapsed*** `TreeView`:

- if we want to see a leaf *(or any not root node)* we have to see/load its parent, grand-parent ... and the root as well.
- but once we want to see a sibling, we do not have to reload all the parent-to-root structure... is is already in play

And that's how the `ui-router` was *basically* designed.