# ui-router rendering ui-views in view templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Just checking an approach for ui-router. Was sure it could do this but hitting some friction. I want my third template to render inside my 2nd template - but my controller is not even initialized for my 3rd state unless I define my ui-view in my 1st template.

Example code

Template 1 This is rendered from an MVC view

```
<div class ="animate-container" ng-app="uiRouter-Browse">   
<div class="products-slide-animate" ui-view="cat1">
        <div>        
            <div><a ui-sref="cat1({id:1})">1</a></div>
        <div><a ui-sref="cat1({id:2})">2</a></div>
        <div><a ui-sref="cat1({id:3})">3</a><div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Template 2

```
<div>
<div class="row all-categories-wrapper">
    <div class="col-xs-12 list-item">
        <a href="#/" class="parent">
            <i class="chevron-left"></i>
            <div>All Categories </div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

<!--want 3rd template to render here -->
<div ui-view="cat2" class="products-slide-animate" autoscroll="false">
<div class="cat2-wrapper" ng-repeat="cat1 in data.Cat1s">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 list-item">
            <a ui-sref="cat2({id:{{cat1.ID}}, name:'{{cat1.UrlEncodedName}}'})">
                <div class="list-item-text">{{cat1.Name}}</div>
                <i class="chevron-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

Template 3

```
<div>
    //some content to render
</div>
```

My ui-router script

```
var browse = angular.module('uiRouter-Browse', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
.run(
    ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
            function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                console.log(toState.name);
                console.log(fromState.name);
            }
        );
    }]);

browse.config(
['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {        
    $urlRouterProvider            
        .otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('cat1', {
            url: '/cat1/:id?name',
            views: {
                'cat1': {
                    templateUrl: '/Template1.html',
                    controller: //Get some data and return
                }
        }})
        .state('cat2', {
            url: '/cat2/:id?name',                
            views: {
                'cat2': {
                    templateUrl: '/Template2.html',
                    controller: //Get some data and return
                }
            }
        });
}]);
```

Most if not all of the examples I see the entire ui-view is replaced, as opposed to partially being replaced - i.e. the rendering of template 3 in the ui-view in template 2.

So when click on the cat 1 links from template 1, it transitions to the next state, the controller is invoked and my animations are pretty.

When I click on a cat2 link, my state is invoked correctly but the controller is not fired. I then just animate back to my previous view/state.

If I place a ui-view="cat2" div in template 1 then the controller fires and my template renders. I just would like it to render within the ui-view in template2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*While not sure if it will really suite to your needs,* the reason and solution is in a different state definition, we need **state nesting**. We simply cannot have two "totally" independent states, and try to inject one into another. We have to make one of them **Parent** and one to be a **Child**:

Current scenario:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('cat1', {
    ...
    }})
    .state('cat2', {
    ...
    });
```

Both states are in this snippet on the same "root" level. If we would like to nest the `cat2` into `cat1` they must be defined like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('cat1', {
    ... // this is a parent
    }})
    .state('cat1.cat2', {
    ... // this is a child
    });
```

That will lead to url for a (sub)state `cat2` to be built from both parent and its own:

```
#/'/cat1/:id/cat2/:id?name&nameurl',
```

but if we do not need Parent url part and its parameters we can use absolute url:

```
.state('cat2', {
        url: '^/cat2/:id?name',
```

See:

- [Methods for Nesting States](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#methods-for-nesting-states)
- [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

Comment: Thanks, I did try there parent property, but not with the absolute URL. Will try. I'm hoping I just need to understand my nesting approach.

Comment: Maybe, here I try to explain how to think about ui-router, maybe it could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/23825238/1679310, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20558850/1679310. Because usin ui-router correctly is about get the right understanding about its design ;)

Comment: Shot bro! Got it. Using the combination of correctly nesting and absolute URLs has done the trick. Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: Great to see that sir, `Enjoy ui-router`, really amazing stuff!