# Page loading with $rootScope variable - variable not set on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm setting `$rootScope.pageLoading = 1` in the router config like this:

```
.state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '',
      templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html',
      resolve: { 
         loading: function($rootScope){
             $rootScope.pageLoading = 1;
         }
     },
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
```

And in the top level of the document, I have a spinner:

```
<!-- page loading -->
<div id="page-loading" ng-show="pageLoading">
    <small-spinner class="spinner fa-spin"></small-spinner>
</div>
```

When a page loads, I cancel the spinner inside the page's controller, like this:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('FilesController', FilesController);

    FilesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Bolt', '$rootScope']

    function FilesController($scope, Bolt, $rootScope){

        activate();

        function activate() {
            var contenttype = 'files';
            var order = 'title';
            var limit = 500;
            var page = 1;

            return Bolt.getRecords(contenttype, order, limit, page)
                .then(function(data){
                    $rootScope.pageLoading = 0;
                });
        }
    }
```

This works fine only when the page is refreshed, i.e. it doesn't work on a simple state change, even though all states are child states of 'app'. What I was going for is that the $rootScope.pageLoading variable is reset whenever a change of state occurs. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557119/angular-ui-router-nested-state-resolve-in-child-states

Comment: Thanks. Sorted now - I needed to watch for the state change with `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(){ // set variable here});`

Answer (score 0):

you should use **$stateChangeStart**

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.pageLoading = 1;
        });
```

Add this to your app controller. Now every time when your state changes, it will reset your pageLoading variable to 1.